# Can the robot reach the target?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

A robot is located on an infinite plane. At the beginning, the robot starts at the coordinates $(0, 0)$. The robot can then make several steps. The steps are numbered starting from $0$.

In each step, robot must choose one of two directions : right ($x$ coordinate increases) or up ($y$ coordinate increases). In step $k$, the robot will move $3^k$ units in the chosen direction. It is not allowed to skip a step.  You are given integers $x$ and $y$. I want to know if it is possible to go to that location or not by returning $1$ for yes and $0$ for no.

Comment: In the above, $(0,0)$ is not reachable (in step $0$ you move $1$, and you are not allowed to skip a step). Was this your intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check: $x+y$ should be a $\sum_{i=0}^k 3^i=\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$ for some $k$. Deeper check: the powers should be distributed nicely between $x$ and $y$. Fortunately, $3^k>\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}3^i$, so that the following algorithm works:

1. Let $s\leftarrow 2(x+y)+1$.
2. If $x<y$ swap $x\leftrightarrow y$. *[Swapping does not affect solvability, but simplifies treatment]*
3. If $y<0$ terminate with "no". *[Points with negative coordinates cannot be reached]*
4. If $s=1$, terminate with "yes". *[Implies $x=y=0$ and that point can be reeached with no step at all]*
5. If $s$ is not divisible by $3$, terminate with "no". *[Because all powers of $3$ except $3^0$ are multiples of $3$]*
6. Let $s\leftarrow \frac s3$. *[That is, the previous power of $3$, also the top summand in $\sum 3^i$]*
7. Let $x\leftarrow x-s$ and go to step 2. *[By the observation above, the top summand must have been the last step for the bigger coordinate; steps 6 and 7 effectively undo the last step]*

Comment: Damn, you're fast.

Comment: @Hagen von whats there in step 5?

Comment: @user3001932 Please check again, I just rearranged the steps

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Excellent explanation +1 for it

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ the the set of pairs $(x,y)$ that can be reached.

Write $x,y$ as  $x=\sum_{k=0}^n x_k 3^k$, $y=\sum_{k=0}^n y_k 3^k$, with $n = \lfloor \log_3 \max(x,y)\rfloor+1$.

(This is just the base 3 expansion of the integers $x,y$.)

Then $(x,y) \in R$ **iff** $x_k+y_k = 1$ for $k=0,...,n$.

**Aside**: Note that this is different than finding the base 3 expansion of $x+y$. For example, $(x,y) = (2,2)$ is not in $R$, but $(x+y)_3 =11_3$.

**Algorithm**:

1. Write $x = 3 n_x+r_x$, $y = 3 n_y + r_y$
2. If $r_x+r_y \neq 1$ **return** $(x,y) \notin R$
3. If $n_x=0$ and $n_y=0$ **return** $(x,y) \in R$
4. $x \leftarrow n_x$, $y \leftarrow n_y$
5. **goto** Step 1

Comment: How are u finding this xk and yk?

Comment: Base 3 expansion of the integers $x,y$. Keep dividing by 3 and save the remainders until you hit zero. Example, $x=10$, $100=33\cdot 3 +1$, $33 = 11 \cdot 3 + 1$, $11=3 \cdot 3 +2$, $3 = 1 \cdot 3 + 0$, $1 = 0 \cdot 3 + 1$, hence $100_{10} = 10201_3$.